# How to store data by increment by +1 every time stored

Tags: laravel

This is my product table.I want to store customer_id from 1000 and save by +1 how much data i stored

```
id  |  customer_id      |  name       |  
1   |      1000       |   ABC       |
2   |      1001       |   Tripathi  |
3   |      1002       |   Leaptrig  |
4   |      1003       |   Falcon    |
5   |      1004       |   Savillan  |
6   |      1005       |  Molt       |
7   |      1006       |   Falt      |
```

My Controller

```
        $lastProduct=Product::pluck('customer_id')->last();
        $product=new Product();
        $product->name=$request->name;
        if($lastProduct){
          $product->customer_id=1000+($lastProduct+1);
        }
        $product->save();
```

But In this code,Customer id i increment by 1000 2001,3002 like this. so how should i avoid it ?

```
id  |  customer_id      |  name       |  
1   |      1000       |   ABC       |
2   |      2001       |   Tripathi  |
3   |      3002       |   Leaptrig  |
4   |      4003       |   Falcon    |
5   |      5004       |   Savillan  |
6   |      6005       |  Molt       |
7   |      7006       |   Falt      |
```

Comment: why dont use the incremental `id` and add 1000 when showing the data ? or even better, in the migration of the database, make the incrementor start from 1000 instead of 1 and let the database handle it.

Comment: Suppose ,  `$lastProduct = 1000;` so now `1000+($lastProduct+1)` will be `1000 + (1000+1)`  = `2001`, so the next will be `3002`. The code is eorking fine according your method, cause you added `1000 + 1` on every new instance

Comment: Change `$product->customer_id=1000+($lastProduct+1);` to `$product->increment('customer_id');`

Comment: @sta Suppose i have 900 data in database.How to write SQL statement to change all customer_id starting from 1000 and end with customer_id 1900

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :-

```
$lastProduct=Product::pluck('customer_id')->last();
$product=new Product();
$product->name=$request->name;
if($lastProduct){
   $product->customer_id=$lastProduct+1;
}
$product->save();
```